# How to have pyautogui turn a hotkey into a variable

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to get pyautogui to copy a number, then turn that number into a variable. Here is my code that is trying to achieve that but it just returns "none". How do I fix this? I want it to copy the number then turn test1 into that number amount.

```
pyautogui.mouseDown()
pyautogui.moveRel(100, 0) #####FIND DOLLAR AMOUNT MOVE
pyautogui.mouseUp()
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
test1 = pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
print(test1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Hampus Larsson is right: in order to collect data you need to use the clipboard. An alternative way is to use pyperclip module and the `paste` method from there.

For example:

```
import pyperclip

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
test1 = pyperclip.paste()
```

Answer (score 1):

`pyautogui` doesn't doesn't return a value with the method `hotkey()`, so when you try to save the output, you just capture the "none" that the method returns by default.

If you want to gather what you just copied, then you will need to target the clipboard of your computer. If you're running Windows, then that is relatively simple. Just use Powershell!

```
import subprocess
clipboard = subprocess.check_output("powershell.exe Get-Clipboard", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
clipboard = clipboard.decode() #Subprocess.check_output() returns bytes, so if you want to handle it like a string, this is needed to "decode" it.
```

As you can see above, I simply used the windows Powershell to execute the command `Get-Clipboard` which returns a string representation of whatever you have in your clipboard. The only downside to using this method of retrieval is that you have to wait while your computer opens up a Powershell-window in the background and executes the command.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is this the only way? I will use it and you are great help.

Comment: It's not the only way to solve the problem. There are multiple ways to capture the Clipboard that doesn't involve calling powershell, but this was the cleanest solution that I could make using only what is available in a default install of Python. I've seen others using "pyperclip" to gather it in different threads for example.

Comment: Are there any more questions that you have regarding this? Otherwise, could you please mark the question as answered?